# Why are my Intel VLAN virtual NICs stuck in a disabled state?

Tags: windows, network-adapter, vlan

I am using [Intel Advanced Network Services VLANs](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/support/articles/000005677/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html) via the PROSet driver. This allows me to create virtual NICs in Windows that belong to specific 802.1Q tagged VLANs.

After an update to Windows 10 2004, the VLAN adapters are stuck in a "disabled" state. I can try to enable them, but they stay disabled - no error messages, no event logs, etc..

How can I enable these adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enable ANS on the physical NIC

In the course of an upgrade, the ANS driver can be disabled on the NIC. Go to the physical NIC properties (not the virtual VLAN ones) and make sure the "Intel(R) Advanced Network Services Protocol" entry is ticked:

[image: Screenshot of NIC properties]

## Update your drivers

Unfortunately, Intel has not been very good about updating their drivers in time for new Windows 10 major versions. This has broken ANS before, in the 1809 update. In that case, there is nothing to do apart from waiting for a new driver version from them. You might find more information on the [Intel ethernet product forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/bd-p/ethernet-products), including any estimated update timelines.

After a driver update you might need to re-create the VLAN NICs via ANS, and also enable the ANS protocol driver again, as above.

In the case of the 2004 update, new drivers were released towards the end of June 2020.

### Roll back Windows

If you've confirmed via the Intel forums that your current Windows version is not supported, the only thing you can do is roll back to the previous version of Windows and wait for a driver update before upgrading again.

Comment: It would appear that windows 11 does not yet work unfortunately.

Comment: @xorinzor Please consider reporting that [on the Intel forums](https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/bd-p/ethernet-products).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described by Intel in the 2019 article
[How to set up VLANs with an Intel® Ethernet Adapter under Windows® 10 (Build 1809)?](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000035837/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html)

The article notes:

> Even with the latest Windows 10 driver, the situation would persist:
>
> "The initial version of the Intel® PROSet Adapter Configuration
> Utility doesn't include support for Advanced Network Services
> including Team and VLAN configurations. We plan to add this
> functionality to the Intel® PROSet Adapter Configuration Utility in a
> future release" (Refer to [Intel® Ethernet SW 23.5 Release
> Information](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000031823/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html)).

The article offers a temporary workaround using PowerShell:

> 1. From Device Manager, disable the NIC device.
> 2. Remove all drivers and Intel® PROSet software as follows:
>
>    - Access Device Manager*.
>    - Expand Network Adapters.
>    - Right-click each entry of the Intel® Ethernet Adapter.
>    - Click Uninstall Device.
> 3. Once the adapter is uninstalled, cold-boot the system (power off and then back on completely).
> 4. If the device is still disabled, enable it.
> 5. Download, unzip and install [the latest driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/36773/Ethernet-Products)
>    for your Intel® Ethernet Network Adapter as follows:
>
>    - Open the Command Prompt as an Administrator.
>    - Access the folder that is made after having unzipped the Intel® Ethernet Adapter driver package.
>    - Within the Command prompt, go to APPS > PROSETDX > Winx64.  In this folder, run the following command to install the driver along
>      with PROSet and the Advanced Network Settings: `DxSetup.exe BD=1 PROSET=1 ANS=1`
> 6. Reboot the computer.
> 7. Open the Windows* PowerShell (click [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023545/network-and-i-o.html)
>    for the Windows* PowerShell commands), as Administrator, and proceed
>    as follows:
>
> - Run the following command (see below):
>
>   ```
>   Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Intel\Wired Networking\IntelNetCmdlets\IntelNetCmdlets"
>   ```
> - Type "Get-IntelNetAdapter" to display the name of your network adapter.
> - Proceed adding a/the Virtual Local Area Networks (VLANs) by running the *Add-IntelNetVLAN* command and follow the on-screen
>   instructions.
> - Note: When prompted for "*ParentName*",  use the name of the network adapter from the "Get-IntelNetAdapter" output.

Comment: I am more then willing to cleanup comments when it makes sense to clean them up.  Please improve the quality of this answer.  I suppose I should have been clear, I don't believe this answer is accurate, and is not helpful to the community for that reason.

Comment: The quoted article only applies to the ANS versions from 2019. The more recent versions in late 2019 and 2020 do support ANS configuration via the GUI utility, as they said they planned to back then (in your first quote). Change seems to have come through in either 24.5 or 25.0. The PowerShell cmdlets do still work, but they no longer do anything different from the GUI utility. More importantly, those cmdlets doesn't do anything either if you're on 2004 with outdated (pre-25.1.1) drivers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I enable these adapters?

Intel confirmed the VLAN support was not supported with SW Release 25.1, on `Windows 10 version 2004`, at the beginning of June 2020

> We have confirmed that ANS for 20H1 is not supported in SW Release 25.1. ANS support including Teams and VLAN configuration will be available for Windows 20H1 with SW Release 25.1.1.  SW Release 25.1.1 will be available hopefully before the end of the month.

Source: [Intel VLANs not working in Windows 10 2004 (20H1)](https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/Intel-VLANs-not-working-in-Windows-10-2004-20H1/td-p/642684)

Intel released [SW Release 25.1.1](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Complete-Driver-Pack?v=t) on June 16th 2020 which specifically indicates support for both *Windows 10 version 2004* and *Windows Sever version 2004*